# Indexhibit manual upgrade

Tags: php, upgrade, indexhibit

A friend of mine asked me to help her with a website she has that stopped working. The site stopped working after her hosting provider one.com upgraded PHP. She didn't act on the mails they sent well in advance.

The site is an IndexHibit site. I do not know the version of it. But the folder structure is this

```
    /admin
    /files
    /ndxz-studio
```

She is unable to log into the admin site up upgrade IndexHibit.

I tried downloading the latest version from GitHub (https://github.com/Indexhibit/indexhibit) and replace the config.php file. But this wasn't good enough... I didn't expect it to be that easy.

I haven't been able to find information about how to manually upgrade IndexHibit or how to identify the version installed.

I hope someone can help me help her :-)

Comment: Personally, I would re-evaluate my decisions in 2019 for a PHP code that does not use composer and contains several types of security issues reported by people but does not fixed: https://github.com/Indexhibit/indexhibit/issues TLDR; Upgrading is not a solution IMHO. Good luck with it.

Comment: I get that... but at this point she would really like to get access to content etc, so she can move it.